# Can you use dereferencing to call a pointer to a function in assembly?

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, masm

Exactly how it sounds.
I load the `OFFSET` of a procedure into a register, then try to call that register:

```
MOV EBX, OFFSET MyProc
CALL EBX
```

At first I would assume that this will call the function, however when you call a procedure you don't type `CALL OFFSET MyProc`, you simply type `CALL MyProc`.
In C you can call a pointer to a function with the `*` operator: `(*MyProc)();`.
Which leads me to wonder if dereferencing the pointer to the function would call the procedure.

`CALL [EBX]`

However if I dereference it, masm tells me that I need to specify a size, the only possible sizes that I am aware of that I *could* specify are `DWORD PTR`, `WORD PTR`, and `BYTE PTR`, and I don't think that a procedure is of a particular **size**.

To sum it up, can you call a pointer to a procedure simply by directly supplying the pointer as an operand to the call instruction, or would you have to dereference the pointer in the call instruction?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `CALL EBX`? Have you verified that it doesn't do what you need? Because I think it does.

Comment: You can call by dereferencing a pointer. When you use `DWORD PTR` the important thing to consider is what size is _the pointer_, not what size is the function. If you're in 32 bits, then a pointer has 32 bits and is the size of a DWORD. So `DWORD PTR` should be used.

Whether or not you want to call a function like that is up to you, since `call ebx` is different than `call dword ptr [ebx]`. In those cases, the best thing to do is try it out and see what happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `CALL OFFSET MyProc` - because that would be annoying to type every time, and the inconsistent syntax didn't bother MASM creators much (consider the `mov eax,var1` vs `mov eax,[ebx]`, both dereferencing memory).

The `call [ebx]` would fetch the value stored at `ebx` address and use that as final target address, so in your case it would try to interpret the first instructions of procedure as target address, and jump who-know-where (probably causing illegal access crash from OS).

The required size in such case is not classic integer size, but jump/call addresses size, like `NEAR PTR` and `FAR PTR`, which affects how many bytes from memory will be used (`NEAR PTR` in 32b mode is 32b wide vs 16b in real mode (just offset part), `FAR PTR` is 32b in real mode (16b offset + 16b segment), and 48b in 32b protected mode (32b offset + 16b segment, which works more like selector or something, I never actually needed to fully understand this one, so consult your favourite x86 documentation/book for details).